# Google Map for Android doesn't show in production version of App - API key is unrestricted

Tags: android, google-maps

Maps worked properly for debug version and also for first four release versions (Alpha testing).
Now debug version works okay, but maps don't show in new release version. I also added SH1 from my Google Play Console of course, but still nothing. Now I generated new API key and also this key is unrestricted, so it should be always work, but still maps is "white" with Google logo in left down corner

Answer (score 0):

It was my stupid silly mistake. I had one google_maps_api.xml with API key which I added manually at the beginning with my first map fragment. Later I added another map fragment automatically via Android studio. This added two google_maps_api.xml more. So finally I had google_maps_api.xml in

- src/main/res/value
- src/release/res/value
- src/debug/res/value
  In the src/release/res/value/google_maps_api.xml I had "YOUR_KEY_HERE" instead of API key.
  Bottom question:
  I deleted both release and debug files and I have only one in main. If I want to have only one API key for debug and release, is there any other reason to have two google_maps_api.xml files in release and debug folders instead of only one file in main?